# local mailsystem with Postfix, Dovecot: MUA is tricked with wrong address information while sending to alias address?

Tags: postfix-mta, thunderbird, dovecot

I have a local mailsystem with postfix, dovecot, virtual users, postfixadmin and getmail. Everything is working so far, except aliases.
Aliases are delivered to the (expanded) recipients correctly, but a MUA is tricked to supply wrong **From:** and **To:** addresses when clicking reply.

If I view an arriving message within my MUA (Thunderbird in this case), everything seems to be ok:

```
From-field: initial-sender@example.com
To-field: my-alias@mydomain.de
```

If I check the **source of the eMail**, I can see the (in my understanding) correct address information:

```
From: initial-sender@example.com (<= this should get the To: address in a reply-email)
To: my-alias@mydomain.de 
Envelope-To: real-target-behind-alias@anotherdomain.de (<= this should get the From: address in a reply-email)
Return-Path: initial-sender@example.com (<= back to this address in case of error)
```

So far, so good. But if I click "Reply" now, Thunderbird prefills the address fields with wrong information:

```
From-field: initial-sender@example.com
To-field: my-alias@mydomain.de
```

So, that means I would send the reply-email in the name of the initial sender (which I am not) to my own alias.

Why is Thunderbird tricked into this fault?

Best regards, Alex

Comment: No one? At least can anybody tell me which information from the sourcecode of an email is used to fill the To and From fields of Thunderbird when replying to an email?